# How do I increase axis labels and legend size in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my axis labels and legend to look bigger and I want to increase font size

My code:

> `ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-2, 2)), aes((x),xname ='wind') ) +
>     stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = -0.05116279, sd = 0.5725349),                                                  aes(colour = "1 hour"))  +xlab("wind_speed_Error",cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5) +
>     stat_function(fun=dnorm, args = list(mean = -0.355, sd = 0.6602059),  aes(colour = "4 hour"))  +
>     scale_colour_manual("Predictions",values=c("blue","red"))`

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `theme` to access `title` and `legend` font sizes as below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-2, 2)), aes((x), xname ="wind")) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = -0.05116279, sd = 0.5725349), aes(colour = "1 hour"))  +
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, args = list(mean = -0.355, sd = 0.6602059),  aes(colour = "4 hour"))  +
  scale_colour_manual("Predictions", values=c("blue","red")) +
  xlab("wind_speed_Error") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(1.5)),
        legend.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)),
        legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5)))
```